# Matlab on Android

Tags: applications

I know [matlab mobile was just released for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathworks.matlabmobile&hl=en).

Nowadays several mobiles got hardware enough to run some decent calculations...

So question is: Is there a way to run matlab offline on a emulator (like [octave](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octave&hl=en) does) or another workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with the term 'emulator'. Octave uses a terminal emulator, so that's software running in Android. On this site the term emulator usually refers to software running a version of Android so you don't need a phone. Could you please elaborate on what exactly you mean by 'run offline on an emulator'?

Comment: @THelper Ok you`re right. Running offline would be making the calculations on the phone`s hw. But matlab mobile requires you to send data to your server (or cloud) so you get the results done.

Comment: A MATLAB Android port is now available on Google Play. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mathworks.matlabmobile
Also worth to mention is Addi, an open source "mathematical computing environment like Matlab and Octave" aviliable on F-Droid, at https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/com.addi